# cakephp deep conditions from controller

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to get records from CoursesEmployee model within my BusinessesController. They are not linked directly which is my problem.

Each Business has Employees which can enrol in courses.

BusinessesController.php:

```
    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array('Business.' . $this->Business->primaryKey => 1)
    );
    $test =  $this->Business->find('all', $options);
    debug($test);
```

The output:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Business' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Test Business',
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'business_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Keith Power',
            'Business' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Test Business',
            ),
            'Course' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'name' => 'Manual Handling',
                    'CoursesEmployee' => array(
                        'id' => '1',
                        'employee_id' => '1',
                        'course_id' => '1',
                        'course_module_id' => '1',
                        'completed' => true
                    )
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'id' => '3',
                    'name' => 'Induction',
                    'CoursesEmployee' => array(
                        'id' => '2',
                        'employee_id' => '1',
                        'course_id' => '3',
                        'course_module_id' => '0',
                        'completed' => false
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
)
```

**I wish to get the list of CoursesEmployee where CoursesEmployee.completed = true and Business.id = 1**

Model Associations:

Business $hasMany Employee

Employee $belongsTo Business

Employee $hasAndBelongsToMany Course

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Course' => array(
        'className' => 'Course',
        'joinTable' => 'courses_employees',
        'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'course_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

CoursesEmployee

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Employee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Course' => array(
        'className' => 'Course',
        'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

cakephp 2.5

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this way, if it doesn't work we'll try join way :

**updated :**

```
 $coursesEmployes = $this->Business->Employee->CoursesEmployee->find('all',array(
                                'conditions'=>array('CoursesEmployee.completed '=>  'true' ,'Employee.business_id' => '1' ),
                                'recursive'=>3)
                        );
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gives an sql error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Business.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: see my update plz , what's the column designed as foreign key for Business in Employee ?

Comment: the foreign key is business_id